# Creating a datepicker with options to pick month or date range

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I'm working on a WebApp in flask and I'm creating templates in HTML/JS for the front end. I need a datepicker which will allow the user to pick a specific date range, OR let the user pick month range.

Please see image below.

[image: Link to image]

If the user clicks "Month" along the bottom, the user will be given the option to pick a start and end month. But if the user clicks "custom range" like it currently shows, the user can pick between two specific dates and scroll through months.

Any ideas?

Edit: To Clarify, I'm asking if there is anything available that would fit my needs, or do I need to create a datepicker from scratch?

Comment: what is the codes to set the date in js? tell us what library is used to show this screenshot. codes?

Comment: @phonemyatt The image is an example of what I want to do, I don't have access to the code for that.

Answer (score 1):

For newer browsers, you can use HTML [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date/). It is probably simplest, but it doesn't allow to pick data range.

```html
<label for="start">Start date:</label>

<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2018-07-22"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
```

There are some HTML/CSS/JS datapickers:

- [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)
- [Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Material](https://material-ui.com/demos/pickers/)
- [Datapicker (jQuery)](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/)
- [Datepicker (Bootstrap)](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
- [Data range picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)

There are also [other datapickers](https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/50-Best-Date-Time-Picker-jQuery-Plugins.html) available.

Some of them doesn't allow to use date range but it is possible to tweek some of them. There are some guides how to do this depending of selected datapicker.

One that simply allow range is [date range picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/). You should include jQuery, Moment.js and Date Range Picker's files in your webpage and then config it using JavaScript.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
```